# iOS Swift orientation change animation missing

Tags: ios, swift, animation, landscape, portrait

I'm writing an app in Swift 2.0. The app works fine in every aspect, beside one.
When I tilt the screen of both device and emulator the orientation change animation is missing. Instead of a smooth rotation I get a clunky orientation change. Portrait -> Landscape. Nothing in between.
Giving the fact that the animation should be the default, I would like to know if anybody knows the possible solution to this problem. I searched everywhere and apparently nobody has this problem, instead people try to disable that animation!

Comment: Do you have something in app delegate did finish launching ? Sometimes that might cause troubles.

Comment: I do have something in app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. There I'm declaring my container view controller. That's what I'm using to implement a left drawer-menu

Comment: This is an old iOS bug, try removing everything from that and check the results

Comment: mh, but I need those things...

Comment: You will need a workaround for that. As I said its a bug

Comment: well, it was quite easy! I tried to put the same code in applicationDidBecomeActive and it worked! I'll run some tests and see if there are any problems but i think that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests and thanks to Zell.B, I moved the code from didFinishLaunchWithOptions to applicationDidBecomeActive and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the applicationDidFinishLaunching method from the app delegate class can also cause the lack of animation problem.  Adding it back in can fix it.